# Screen-ready accessible hidden content

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers

I have a promotional area with an image and some text wrapped in a 'a' tag, followed by a button that when clicked, shows some terms and conditions as an overlay over the promotional content.

All works fine, but I am having issues to get a screenreader to read he contents of the overlay/terms & conditions box. Even when the terms & conditions button is tabbed to and clicked, it shows, but then pressing tab just jumps to the next section on the page.

Ideally the terms & conditions content would only be read when the button is clicked and appears visible on the page.

No content is being hidden from the flow. I am using the below to position off screen.
I have been testing using VoiceOver on a Mac.

```
<style>
.no-vis {position:absolute; left:-10000px; top:auto; width:1px; height:1px; overflow:hidden;
</style>

<div class="hp_card_con">
        <a href="">
            <div class="card_img-hov">
                <img src="" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card_text">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                <span class="card_link">Shop now</span>
            </div>
        </a>    
        <button class="caption-link" id="caption-link-1">
            <span>Terms and Conditions</span>
        </button>
        <div class="caption-content no-vis" id="caption-1">
            <div class="caption-content-close" id="content-close-1"></div>
            <div class="scroll-content">
                Aliquam sit amet venenatis dui. Ut facilisis at dui vitae gravida. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> pressing tab just jumps to the next section on the page

Assuming the "Aliquam sit..." is your overlay, there are no keyboard focusable elements in the overlay so tabbing won't take you to the content.

You may want to consider implementing your overlay as a dialog and follow the [accessible dialog pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/dialog-modal/).

You could also implement your overlay inside a live region by using [`aria-live`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live), but instead of using `left:-10000px` to "hide" the overlay, use `display:none`. Then when you set `display:block` (or whatever display value you want) and your overlay is contained in a live region, it'll be announced automatically by the screen reader.

```html
<div aria-live="polite">
        <div class="caption-content no-vis" id="caption-1">
            <div class="caption-content-close" id="content-close-1"></div>
            <div class="scroll-content">
                Aliquam sit amet venenatis dui. Ut facilisis at dui vitae gravida. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

If you have an animation effect with the overlay displaying, then I think you have to use `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none`, otherwise the animation doesn't play.